# Why cant I use jwt.verify() from jsonwebtoken in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, jwt

When I use the function of jwt.verify() or jwt.decode() in react, it shows me a lot of errors.

The errors are:

```txt
ERROR in ./node_modules/jwa/index.js 5:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\client\node_modules\jwa'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/jwa/index.js 9:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'C:\Users\client\node_modules\jwa'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
    - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "util": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js 4:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\client\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js 6:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'C:\Users\client\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
    - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "util": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js 8:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\client\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js 12:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'C:\Users\client\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
    - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "util": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js 8:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\client\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js 12:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'C:\Users\client\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
    - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "util": false }
```

NOTE: I try to do the recomendations that the errros say, but it dont fixes it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`jsonwebtokens` is a JWT library for node.js not for JS in the browser. Try one of the libraries listed under JavaScript:
https://jwt.io/libraries?language=JavaScript